# Create multiple tempfiles in perl

Tags: perl

How do I create 6 (six) temp files in perl and get their names for calls to `system())?

I want to optimize this pseudo code:

```
my $TEMP0 = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );
system("PROGRAM0 --output $TEMP0");
my $TEMP1 = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );
system("PROGRAM1 --input $TEMP0 --output $TEMP1");
my $TEMP2 = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );
system("PROGRAM2 --input $TEMP0 --output $TEMP2");
my $TEMP3 = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );
system("PROGRAM3 --input $TEMP1 $TEMP2 --output $TEMP3");
my $TEMP4 = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );
system("PROGRAM4 --input $TEMP3 --output $TEMP4");
my $TEMP5 = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );
system("PROGRAM4 --input $TEMP4 --output $TEMP5");
```

and at the end unlink all of the tempfiles:

```
unlink($TEMP0);
unlink($TEMP1);
unlink($TEMP2);
unlink($TEMP3);
unlink($TEMP4);
unlink($TEMP5);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use map with a range to generate the tempfiles. eg.

```
my @tempfiles = map { new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 ) } 1..6;
```

As there isn't a set pattern in how the programs are called, it seems reasonable to keep them as separate calls to system.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine, just keep `@tempfiles` around until you want the files unlinked.

```
my @tempfiles = map {
  File::Temp->new( UNLINK => 1, use_exlock => 0 );
} 0..5;

system("PROGRAM0 --output $tempfile[0]");
system("PROGRAM1 --input $tempfile[0] --output $tempfile[1]");
system("PROGRAM2 --input $tempfile[0] --output $tempfile[2]");
system("PROGRAM3 --input $tempfile[1] $tempfile[2] --output $tempfile[3]");
system("PROGRAM4 --input $tempfile[3] --output $tempfile[4]");
system("PROGRAM4 --input $tempfile[4] --output $tempfile[5]");

...

undef @tempfiles; # unlink all
```

If it would actually make more sense for the files to be associated with some internal name, write it like this:

```
my %tempfiles = map{
  $_ => File::Temp->new( UNLINK => 1, use_exlock => 0 );
} qw'zero one two three four five';


system("PROGRAM0 --output $tempfile{zero}");
system("PROGRAM1 --input $tempfile{zero} --output $tempfile{one}");
system("PROGRAM2 --input $tempfile{zero} --output $tempfile{two}");
system("PROGRAM3 --input $tempfile{one} $tempfile{two} --output $tempfile{three}");
system("PROGRAM4 --input $tempfile{three} --output $tempfile{four}");
system("PROGRAM4 --input $tempfile{four} --output $tempfile{five}");

...

undef %tempfiles; # unlink all
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my @tempfiles = map { new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 ) } 1 .. 6;

system("PROGRAM0 --output $tempfiles[0]");

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $#tempfiles ; $i++ ) {
    system( "PROGRAM0 --output ", $tempfiles[$i], " --input ", $tempfiles[ $i - 1 ] );
}

unlink(@tempfiles);
```